# Sound no longer works. Soundcard still recognised

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, soundcard

Booted into OS the other day, sound no longer works. Nothing comes out. I tried a few tips I found on the net, but I think I've made things worse, as the sound icon in the taskbar is now gone.

My soundcard (Asus Essence STX), is still recognised in info centre, hardinfo, VLC, pretty much anywhere and every where, etc.

I've re-installed alsa and pulse.

totally stuck, no idea what to do, and I have nfi what caused the problem in the first place.. please help!

edit: forgot details - I'm on 20.04LTS. Only thing I've been installing / changing is OS updates
edit2: I'm also a massive linux n00b, only been using it for ~16 months

Comment: cheers, forgot that, sorry.. have edited OP to show info! :)

Comment: I've made progress!

using cmd 'alsamixer', then press F5 (All), scroll sideways until 'Analogue Output' is selected, change output to 'Headphones' (I can select between Headphones, Headphones FP, & Speakers). I then restarted PC... settings didn't stick. Also, the sound icon still doesn't show. Also forgot to mention in OP, the 'Audio' settings in main system settings GUI does not show at all.. it's like theres a missing layer between OS and soundcard. Is there anyway to do a partial OS restore, so that I don't have to re-install everything?